# Unique ids using a static variable in C

Tags: c, static

I need to give certain nodes in my tree unique ids as they are recursively added. I wrote code like this to solve the problem:

```
  } else if (deapTree[0] == -1){
    static int const_idx;
    //bla bla bla
    root->idx = const_idx;
    //bla bla bla
    const_idx++; 
  } else {
```

Will this work as I intend? Meaning `const_idx` will start at 0, and then every time that branch of the `if` is reached it'll get incremented by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for single-threaded programs. For multi-threaded programs, you need to use `_Atomic`.

That said, I recommend refactoring it out to a separate function.

Alternatively, consider moving the counter from a global variable to a member of the tree root itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work as expected.